# Can materials be melted using code?

Tags: 3d, models, unreal

Say this ball for example :

[image: Ball morphing]

These three models have been created, to then use a simple morph transition to make the ball switch from 0 to 1 then to 2, and make it look like it's melting.

But is it possible to make a material that can be melted programatically? without need of having to make models for every object I want to be interacted with? And is it possible to make it as realistically looking as the first one shown in the pictures?

Comment: If you weren't using a game engine and actually making the game yourself or if you have access to the ball's mesh then it shouldn't be too difficult. Do you?

Comment: Perhaps if you assumed your models suddenly turned to some kind of fluid? Maybe fluid mechanics is one way to do it?